# Android: Changing the camera preview size on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

Currently, the Camera Preview is stretched to fit the entire screen (854x480). I'd like it to display (427x240) instead.

Here is the relevant code for the camera implementation:

> ```
> Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
> params.setPreviewSize(427, 240); 
> mCamera.setParameters(params);
> ```

```
public class CameraTest extends Activity {    
    private Preview mPreview;
    private DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        // Create our DrawOnTop view.
        mDrawOnTop = new DrawOnTop(this);
        mPreview = new Preview(this, mDrawOnTop);
        setContentView(mPreview);
        addContentView(mDrawOnTop, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

saw this on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html):

> If you want to set a specific size for your camera preview, set this
>   in the surfaceChanged() method as noted in the comments above. When
>   setting preview size, you must use values from
>   getSupportedPreviewSizes(). Do not set arbitrary values in the
>   setPreviewSize() method.

and wrote this to get the smallest:

```
        List<Size> list = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Size size = list.get(0);
    int height = size.height;
    int minHeight=9999999;
    for(int i = 0; i<=list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).height<minHeight){
            minHeight = list.get(i).height;
        }
    }
```

hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

mCamera.setParameters(params);
only set the parameters. It will be passed to camera hardware.

To set preview window size, you have to modify the camera layout file.